# Unorthodox Prof. Roman’s Chemistry Class Quiz

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Prof. Roman of Chemistry department as you all know is quite unorthodox..here is his Quiz. It is Monday Morning and it is time for Prof. Roman’s unusual quizzes to his chemistry class.

What is the missing letter?

$C$, $N$, $D$, $Q$, $?$

Comment: chemistry tag? knowledge? math?

Comment: Nope..I put right tag...no other tags needed except knowledge..will add

Comment: I suggest you not using the words chemistry when it doesn't help at all but mislead the solvers...

Comment: Will do..but is clearly stated in the puzzle..he gives off topic quizzes..if it is less confusing..I will refrain in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This set of us may continue:

> C, N, D, Q, (H), D,

If these represent:

> Cent, Nickel, Dime, Quarter, (Half dollar), Dollar so most commonly a **D**
>   <sub>(I wonder if  Prof. Roman is a grandpa.)</sub>

Comment: why unorthodox and roman? nice try tho

Comment: Got it Tom..continuing from his earlier problem..he loves to test students lateral thinking..no reference to chemistry tag..

Comment: Tom seems to understand Prof. Roman pretty good..he solved his earlier problem too..

Answer (score 0):

What I've got so far:

> In Roman numerals (Since, Prof. Roman)

As follows

> C = 100,
> N = 90,
> D = 500,
> Q = 500 (deprecated)

Comment: Wrong path..you never know what he is going to ask..his students know no subject is off limits for him..

Comment: @pranav I was going the same route since rot13(D pna or pbafvqrerq nf 500,000 va fbzr pnfrf)